# Multiprocessing in a while loop, program hangs after a period of time

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

So I've got a program that I've been working on. It takes a while to run and I am trying to optimize its run time by offloading certain parts of it to multiple processes using the multiprocessing library.

However, while I'm pretty sure I've implemented my processes properly and that the portion of code I am offloading is possible to run in parallel I'm having the issue where the code hangs after a variable number of loops. It doesn't appear to be a lack of RAM.

Please take a look at the code below. I've included the original code, the new code, the different functions involved and the runtime code.

I will try to answer any questions quickly.

Original code:

```
rStack = randStack()
listMaster=[]
while True:     
    if len(listMaster) == 0: #Checks if list is empty. A Python list will evaluate False if there is nothing in it.
        pt = randomSpherePt()# Generate point on sphere
        pt.append(R) # append rho
        listMaster = np.asarray(pt) # Add point to master list
        rStack.push(pt) # Add point to random stack
    else:
        parentPT = rStack.pop() #Grab an 'active' point
        i=1
        while i <= n:
            # Create candidate point in the annulus r1 to r2 around the parent point
            newPT = randAnnulus(parentPT, r1, r2, R)
            #determine if it is less than r1 from any point in the master list. If so throw it out and move on, otherwise keep it and exit loop
            angles = GCD_Angle(newPT, listMaster, method = None)
            test = angles < r1/R
            if test.any():
                pass
            else:
                listMaster = np.vstack((listMaster, newPT))
                rStack.push(newPT)
                break
            i += 1
        if i >= n: #If the loop fails to generate a valid candidate point remove parent point from consideration.
            pass
        else:
            rStack.push(parentPT)
    if rStack.empty(): #if the random stack is empty after a cycle, there are no more point to place. End loop
        break
return listMaster
```

Multiprocessing Code:

```
rStack = randStack()
listMaster=[]
while True:     
    if len(listMaster) == 0: #Checks if list is empty. A Python list will evaluate False if there is nothing in it.
        pt = randomSpherePt()# Generate point on sphere
        pt.append(R) # append rho
        listMaster = np.asarray(pt) # Add point to master list
        rStack.push(pt) # Add point to random stack
    else:
        parentPT = rStack.pop() #Grab an 'active' point
        output = mup.Queue()
        processes = [mup.Process(target=annuliPts,args=(parentPT, r1, r2, R, listMaster,output)) for x in range(n)]
        for p in processes:
            print "Starting process ", p
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
            print "Stoping process ", p

        if output.empty():
            print "No points"
            pass
        else:
            results = [output.get() for p in processes]
            index = rand.choice(np.arange(len(results)))
            newPT = results[index]
            rStack.push(parentPT)
            rStack.push(newPT)
            listMaster = np.vstack((listMaster,newPT))
        print "Finishing pop and mup set"
    if rStack.empty(): #if the random stack is empty after a cycle, there are no more point to place. End loop
        break
    return listMaster
```

Auxiliary Code:

```
class randStack():
    '''
    This is a random access stack.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.array) <= 0

    def length(self):
        return len(self.array)

    def push(self,x):
        self.array.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        n = len(self.array)

        if n <= 0:
            raise IndexError('Cannot pop from empty stack')
        elif n == 1:
            return self.array.pop()
        else:
            i = np.random.randint(0,n)
            self.array[i], self.array[-1] = self.array[-1],self.array[i]

        return self.array.pop()

def GCD_Angle(pt1,pt2, method = 'vector'):

    if method != 'vector':
        # theta1,phi1,rho1 = pt1
        # theta2,phi2,rho2 = pt2
        del_theta = abs(pt1[0]-pt2[...,0])

        t1 = np.cos(pt2[...,1]) * np.sin(del_theta)
        t2 = np.cos(pt1[...,1]) * np.sin(pt2[...,1]) - np.sin(pt1[...,1]) * np.cos(pt2[...,1]) * np.cos(del_theta)

        top = np.sqrt(t1**2 +t2**2)
        bot = np.sin(pt1[...,1]) * np.sin(pt2[...,1]) + np.cos(pt1[...,1]) * np.cos(pt2[...,1]) * np.cos(del_theta)

        cent_angle = np.arctan2(top,bot)
        return cent_angle

    else:
        pt1c = sph_to_cart(pt1)
        pt2c = sph_to_cart(pt2)
        try:
            V = np.cross(pt1c,pt2c,axisb=1)
            top = np.sqrt(np.sum(V**2,axis=1))
            bot = np.inner(pt1c,pt2c)[0]
        except:
            V = np.cross(pt1c,pt2c)
            top = np.sqrt(np.sum(V**2))
            bot = np.inner(pt1c,pt2c)
        angles=np.arctan2(top,bot)
    return angles       

def randomSpherePt():
    '''Generates a random point on a unit sphere. This method retrieves the machine epsilon (minimal floating point precision) 
    and uses it to generate a float on the all inclusive range [0,1]'''
    epsi = np.finfo(float).eps
    u_1 = rand.uniform(0,1 + epsi)
    u_2 = rand.uniform(0,1 + epsi)

    lam = math.acos(2.0*u_1 - 1.0) - math.pi / 2.0
    phi = 2.0 * math.pi * u_2

    return [lam,phi]

def randAnnulus(pt,r1,r2,R):
    '''This function generates a random point in the annulus "r" to "R" around the point "pt".'''

    theta, phi, rho = pt

    epsi = np.finfo(float).eps

    u_1 = rand.uniform(0, (1 + epsi))
    u_2 = rand.uniform(0, (1 + epsi))

    # generate alphha (azimuth) direction of point
    alpha = 2.0 * math.pi * u_1

    # generate arc distance lambda from point in range r-R (assume on unit sphere)
    lam = math.sqrt(u_2*(r2**2-r1**2)+r1**2)


    # generate spherical coordinates
    phi2 = math.asin(math.cos(alpha)*math.sin(lam)*math.cos(phi) + math.sin(phi)*math.cos(lam))
    theta2 = theta - math.acos((math.cos(lam) - math.sin(phi)*math.sin(phi2)) / (math.cos(phi)*math.cos(phi2)))

    # return coords
    return np.array([theta2,phi2,rho])
```

Runtime Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os, math
import logging
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
import multiprocessing as mup
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rand = np.random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)
    mup.log_to_stderr() 
    logger = mup.get_logger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print "Starting program"
    sph_array = sphere_Poisson_Dist(r1 = 10, r2 = 20, R = 100)
    cart_array = sph_to_cart(sph_array)
    print "Pushing data to visuals"
    x = cart_array[...,0]
    y = cart_array[...,1]
    z = cart_array[...,2]

    ax.scatter(x,y,z)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Should be fixed now, lost a tab in an if loop

Comment: As a suggestion: Add some logging. The output could help you to find the culprit

Comment: Why does Original code has a `return` statement. It is a script isn't it, not a function?

Comment: @ChristianSauer I've got some logging on the multiprocessing version. Doesn't seem to throw anything up but I might need to try at a deeper level.

Comment: @Elmex80s The runtime bit is a script, the rest are functions. This is but one part of a much larger project dealing with terrain generation.

Comment: @AlexM Fair enough, but in that case just give it to us as a function. I am missing a `def` right now.